# how to find the checkbox's text using (search textbox)?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textbox

How to find the checkbox's text using (search textbox) and after a word put it into the textbox and click enter it will display that checkbox based on my coding below. What is the coding to do that? And my checkbox at the [ else if (f && g) { ] are not working. It not display the result what I put. Why? Can anyone fix my coding?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  body,
  h1 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif
  }
  
  img {
    margin-bottom: -7px
  }
  
  input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  
  input[type=text]:focus {}
</style>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <h3><b><label for="search">Search</label></b>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." /></h3>

  <head>
    <script>
      function fungsi() {

        var a = document.getElementById("subSolving1").checked;
        var b = document.getElementById("subSolving2").checked;
        var c = document.getElementById("subSolving3").checked;

        var d = document.getElementById("subConclusion1").checked;
        var e = document.getElementById("subConclusion2").checked;

        var f = document.getElementById("subRepeated1").checked;
        var g = document.getElementById("subRepeated2").checked;

        if (c || d === true) {
          document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem1";
        } else if (b || a || e) {
          document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem2";
        } else if (f) {
          document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem3";
        } else if (g) {
          document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem4";
        } else if (f && g) {
          document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem5";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <b>Origin:</b>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv(Solving) {
        var subSolving = document.getElementById("subSolving");
        subSolving.style.display = Solving.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Solving"> <input type="checkbox" id="Solving" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="Solving"/>Solving</label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv2(Conclusion) {
        var subConclusion = document.getElementById("subConclusion");
        subConclusion.style.display = Conclusion.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Conclusion"> <input type="checkbox" id="Conclusion" onclick="ShowHideDiv2(this)" value="Conclusion"/>Conclusion</label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv3(Repeated) {
        var subRepeated = document.getElementById("subRepeated");
        subRepeated.style.display = Repeated.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Repeated"> <input type="checkbox" id="Repeated" onclick="ShowHideDiv3(this)" value="Repeated"/>
   Repeated</label>

    <div id="subSolving" style="display: none">
      <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving1 
     </label></p>

      <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving2</label></p>

      <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving3" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving3 </label></p></div>

      <div id="subConclusion" style="display: none">

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion
     </label></p>
      </div>

      <div id="subRepeated" style="display: none">
        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated1</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated2
     </label></p>
      </div>

      <b><hr/><p id="Status"></p></b></header>

    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `if` statement is never hit, because if you check f or g checkbox, then code lines where you check only for f or g meets condition. So just move f && g condition just above those two.

```
    if (c || d === true) {
      document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem1";
    } else if (b || a || e) {
      document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem2";
    } else if (f && g) {
      document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem5";
    } else if (f) {
      document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem3";
    } else if (g) {
      document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem4";
    }
```

For search part you need to e a bit more specific.

Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq8adqkv/1/) where you listen for enter key being pressed on search input.

**Edit**

Here's the code, which listens for `keyup` event and if <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, then it just loops through all `<label>` tags, where text is. If this label text contains search string, then `<label>` is displayed, otherwise it is hidden.

```
  function filterWithSearch(e){
    if(e.which === 13 )
    {
      var searchStr = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
      var cxb = document.querySelectorAll("label")
      for(var i = 0; i < cxb.length; i++) {

        if(cxb[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) !== -1){
          cxb[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          cxb[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It look like this. https://embed.plnkr.co/fDzATotA41o9tuxY6vEE/ . But I do not quite understand the coding and I still learning. For search part, to search whatever my checkbox and will display that result only.

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/lK6G4VywYVYnkjLudas0?p=preview

Comment: yes something like that. is it possible does not has link? because I do not quite understand and want to see full coding.

Comment: I mean link in the coding which are src=" " something

Comment: All the code is in the <script> tag. It's quite short function. Which part you need help with?

Comment: When Enter key is pressed at the searchbox, it not display any <label>. Why? I think because when checkbox checked then it will show <lable> otherwise it cannot. So how to solve it?

Comment: can you create a js fiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to create a js fiddle. Why your fiddle when i run it, cannot display any label?

Comment: "..cannot display any label", what do you mean? If I input "1" and press enter, I get "subSolving1" and "subRepeated1". If I input "repeated" and press enter, I get "subRepeated1" and "subRepeated2". If it is not correct, then what is your expected result?

Comment: oh really? that is my expected result. I dont know why I input something and press enter, it not show anything. This is your fiddle right? https://jsfiddle.net/sb4ftsjw/2/

Comment: what happens if you click on "Solving", "Conclusion" or "Repeated" checkbox?

Comment: oh did u mean I have to click on "Solving", "Conclusion" or "Repeated" checkbox than I will get whatever my input? yes it work but what if do not click anything, is it possible to display the result?

Comment: here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wq8adqkv/ on line 41 I added if condition, so if there will be search string, then it will show options which will meet search string.

Comment: still cannot get display the result without me having to click on "Solving", "Conclusion" or "Repeated" checkbox when I input "subSolving1" or something.

Comment: sorry forgot to update. here's good one https://jsfiddle.net/wq8adqkv/1/

Comment: glad to help ;)

Comment: when input something at the searchbox and press enter, the result will display but after that if I want to click on "Solving", "Conclusion" or "Repeated" checkbox the result not display. How to solve it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wq8adqkv/2/ you can follow code I added at in function on line 74. In your code you have many examples showing and hiding html elements, just figure out the logic how you wanna proceed filtering elements and from this point you could do it your self.

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you so much. Really appreciate it. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you organize your html codes, styles, and scripts. Avoid inline coding to prevent confusions. Use external scripts and reference it to your html code.**